# Problems logging log4j 1.X dependencies in log4j 2.X

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, logging, log4j

I am migrating an application to log4j 2.16 and I need the dependencies that have log4j 1.X can log in the application..

The previous implementation ( which worked but I'm not sure it was correct ) used these dependencies :

```xml
    <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And in principle, following the guide of [apache](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html) itself should be to change these libraries and change the methods that invoke the loggers for the appropriate ones.

remaining as follows
[example diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biEBP.png)

```xml
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

But it doesn't work

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource.<clinit>(ConfigurationSource.java:56)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.<init>(NullConfiguration.java:32)
```

With that combination it doesn't fail to build but it doesn't log the 1.X dependencies.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

any ideas ?
PD:

- Java 1.8
- Maven 3.6
- Spring-boot 2.4

Comment: Ditch those dependencies, use `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` instead and add `<log4j2.version>2.16.0</log4j2.version>` in your properties section in maven. In your code use SLF4j don't directly use the underlying library, that saves you modifications each time that API changes.

Comment: Does that include the same functionality as using the pure library ? I have complex log configuration files @M.Deinum

Comment: Yes but that lets spring boot manage the dependencies, instead of you trying to gather all the proper dependencies.

Comment: I get a compile error : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project projectA: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /var/maven/mymaven/projectA/src/main/java/projectA/ClassA.java:[7,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist

Comment: Did you include the `spring-boot-starter-log4j2`?